# How can I create a trigger in Azure Data Factory that only triggers once?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to create a trigger in Azure Data Factory that only triggers once. Sure, I can set a Start date and an End date, but is there a more elegant way of doing that?

Comment: Do you really need a Trigger? If it is for one time use, can you just start it manually?

Comment: No, I can't, because it has to be done in Production, which is done through CI/CD. Doing it manually is not possible.

Comment: That makes sense. Can the CI/CD pipeline call a REST API? You could have it execute the pipeline, or call a Logic App to do it, or an Azure Function. But I don't think there is an good Trigger object for it.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to store flag in database table and read it in master pipeline to set the condition based on flag execute another pipeline, master pipeline can have scheduled trigger, once your operation is completed you can remove trigger programmatically and set flag to 0 or something to avoid unnecessary billing. Also you can execute pipeline using c# code, please look at this [msdnlink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-dot-net#create-a-pipeline-run)

Other way is to trigger from logic app using data factory connector, easy and best way